# Entity Framework Entity Splitting Into a single POCO

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and I want to define a single POCO class (Subscriber) which hydrates itself from three SQL tables.  I have tried to follow various on-line references including this one from [Deliveron](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/entity-splitting-code-first-entity-framework/).  Here are the table/model definitions...

**SQL Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE [Subscriber]
(
    [SubscriberId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Username] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [SubscriberDetails]
(
    [SubscriberId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriberDetails_Subscriber]
        FOREIGN KEY ([SubscriberId])
        REFERENCES [Subscriber] ([SubscriberId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
CREATE TABLE [SubscriberProfile]
(
    [SubscriberId] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Bio] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SubscriberProfile_Subscriber]
        FOREIGN KEY ([SubscriberId])
        REFERENCES [Subscriber] ([SubscriberId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

**Domain Model**

```
public class Subscriber {
    public int SubscriberId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
};
```

In my DataContext OnModelCreating() method, I have added the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriber>()
.HasKey(m => m.SubscriberId)
.Map(m => {
    m.ToTable("Subscriber");
    m.Properties(s => new {
        s.SubscriberId,
        s.UserName,
        s.Email
    });
 })
 .Map(m => {
     m.ToTable("SubscriberDetails");
     m.Properties(s => new {
         s.FirstName,
         s.LastName
     });
 })
 .Map(m => {
     m.ToTable("SubscriberProfile");
     m.Properties(s => new {
         s.Bio
     });
 });
```

Whilst this compiles and loads, when I try and run a query against the DataContext I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name
>   'dbo.Subscriber21'

Can anyone give me any direction on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this an existing database that you're creating a model for? I'm wondering where that object name came from.

Comment: I do notice that you have an extra property mapped (`UserName`) that doesn't exist in the `Subscriber` class, but I'm guessing that's a typo.

Comment: This is an existing/legacy database that we need to map to.  You are correct, I had missed the 'UserName' property from the domain model.  Out of interest, do you have to map every property from every table?

Comment: Have a look at the generated sql, maybe that could point you in the right direction

Comment: I've seen some similar example (in the official EF6 tutorial), there they make it with 2 differences: firstly the `SubscriberId` property should be included in ***all splittings***. that property is missing in your mapping for `SubscriberDetails` and `SubscriberProfile`. Secondly, the `m.ToTable(..` is called ***after*** the `m.Properties(...` in the same mapping. I'm not sure if that's the problem but it's worth trying. Also it's better to show your actual query causing the exception.

Comment: I think I have found the problem.  I was creating two instances of the DbModelBuilder - one directly in the OnModelCreating() method (which I was using to try and debug) and one in some original code via a call to modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubscriberMap());  When I combined the code into one DbModelBuilder instance (in the SubscriberMap) the problem went away.  I had assumed that both instances would build against some common target, but this does not appear to be the case.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.